# Order of an element a group and inner automorphism

Tags: group-theory

Let G be a group. Let $ x \in G $ be an element of order $p$, for some prime $p$. Say for some $y \in G$, $xyx^{-1} = y^p$. The problem is to find possible orders of $y$.

Since $xyx^{-1}$ defines an automorphism, order of $y$ and $y^p$ be must the same. This is possible if and only if order of y is not a multiple of $p$. Thus my answer is that order of  $y$ could be any non-multiple of $p$.

I tried to see if there are further relations because $x^p =1$, but I couldn't see any. My guess is that order of $x$ plays no role here, but I do not have a convincing reason yet.

Comment: If something has order $p$ like this, the indication is to find an appropriate way of operating $p$ times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're wondering how the order of $x$ affects anything. Consider the following:
$$
\begin{align}
y ={}& x^pyx^{-p}\\
={}& x^{p-1}(xyx^{-1})x^{-p+1}\\
={}& x^{p-1}y^px^{-p+1}\\
={}& x^{p-2}(xy^px^{-1})x^{-p+2}\\
={}& x^{p-2}(xyx^{-1}\cdot xyx^{-1}\cdots xyx^{-1})x^{-p+2}\\
={}& x^{p-2}y^{p^2}x^{-p+2}\\
&\vdots\\
={}& y^{p^p}
\end{align}
$$
So $e = y^{p^p-1}$, and therefore the order of $y$ must divide $p^p-1$. As a bonus, this automatically implies $p\nmid \operatorname{ord}y$, so you don't need that as a separate condition.

I don't know whether that's the only general restriction on the order of $y$, so this is not a full answer. But it was too long to put in a comment.

Comment: Many thanks, I completely failed to see this possibility. This perhaps is  not  the most general restriction. But given a p, I shall be able to list possible orders using this, especially for small ps.